# Как убрать с строки 15 символов?

Tags: python

Пишу простой генератор паролей, который генерирует пароль строкового типа ( str )
Хотел бы сделать так, чтобы если пароль генерировался с цифрами и буквами, к примеру на 30 символов вообщем, тогда я как-то в коде мог бы сделать пароль на 15 символов меньше.

Вот как я это понимаю:

```
        password = '^hgKS~jLC?ErZWj^{M^0^2U}e4D*5)'
        password -= 15
```

Но, я понимаю что это строка и сделать её меньше на 15 символов этим кодом не получится.

***Помогите плз***

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
password = password[:-15] # вырезаем из строки с первого по 15 с конца символ
```

P.S. про условия
замените

```
if use_english and use_symbols and use_figures = 'да'
```

на

```
if use_english = 'да' and use_symbols = 'да' and use_figures = 'да'
```

выше условие сделайте аналогично